# Web API CRUD Demo with Console App and MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created a simple CRUD method using Web API project which consumed by 2 platform: Console App and MVC Web Application. The EntityModel project is mainly the entity and the DAL layer. Is my architecture/structure okay in regards to implementing Web Api? Should I have this DTO thingy or do without? There is only one entity which is the Employee class.

```
using EntityModel;
using EntityModel.DAL;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;


namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    private AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();

    // GET api/Employee
    public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return db.Employees;
    }

    // GET api/Employee/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(employee);
    }

    // PUT api/Employee/5
    public IHttpActionResult PutEmployee(int id, Employee employee)
    {

        if (id != employee.EmployeeID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!EmployeeExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST api/Employee
    [ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostEmployee(Employee employee)
    {

        db.Employees.Add(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.EmployeeID }, employee);
    }

    // DELETE api/Employee/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteEmployee(int id)
    {
        Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Employees.Remove(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(employee);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool EmployeeExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Employees.Count(e => e.EmployeeID == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

}

Full solution source code is available in my git - https://github.com/ngaisteve1/WebAPIDemo

[image]

I just check on Microsoft article on Domain-Driven Design. I think I have combined Domain layer and Infrastructure layer, right?

[image]

Comment: I'm not going to do a full review; suffice to say that merely seeing `private AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();` already breaks a cardinal rule. Please read the "lifetime" section @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext . Also, keep your controllers lean: https://jonhilton.net/2016/06/06/simplify-your-controllers-with-the-command-pattern-and-mediatr/ . See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8828946/648075 . See also https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/why-to-avoid-fat-controllers/ . Etc.

Comment: We review only code that is posted in the question so if you have any concerns about your DAL then you should post its code too.

Comment: I have just edited to add the screen shot of my solution structure

Comment: @BCdotWEB thanks. Will look into those items.